# Moving files from screenshots to a different folder

Tags: python, automation

This is the code, it searches for through screenshots and takes those that have a specific string.

```
import os
import shutil
#from pathlib import Path


#'E:\\Test'
#if src = 'path/to/file.txt'
#grabs = 'C:\\Users\\Gal\\Videos\\Captures'
#'C:\\Users\\Gal\\Videos\\Captures'


directory = ('C:\\Users\\Gal\\Videos\\Captures')
target = ('C:\\zorko')
destination = 'zorko'


for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    data = str(filename)
    final = 'teorija' in data
    path = os.path.abspath(filename)
    if final is True:
        print('1')
        shutil.move(filename, target)
```

Howevere when trying to move them with shutil it displays this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'T1A INF teorija _ Microsoft Teams 10_21_2020 10_39_27 AM.png' -> 'C:\\zorko\\T1A INF teorija _ Microsoft Teams 10_21_2020 10_39_27 AM.png'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    shutil.move(filename, target)
  File "C:\Users\Gal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 802, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Gal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Gal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'T1A INF teorija _ Microsoft Teams 10_21_2020 10_39_27 AM.png'
```

Comment: Is the code you posted the actual code that produced that error? Doesn't seem like it, it's 23 lines and the error happens on "line 28". And the paths referenced in your error aren't referenced in your code.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me I had two programs opened for testing purposes and accidentally pasted the error from the other one. I edited the post so it is the right one.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something like `shutil.move(path, target)` and not `shutil.move(filename, target)`?

Comment: I have tried all sorts of combinations including this one (ran it again to be sure), and it doesn't work the error is the same

Comment: @AMC that's exactly what I suggested, read my comment again.

Comment: OP I see you have `import pathlib` commented out, why not use that over `os.path` ?

Comment: @RandomDavis *facepalm* Oops...

Comment: Im new to files in python so os.path.abspath() worked for me and I left it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

directory = ('C:\\Users\\Gal\\Videos\\Captures')
target = ('C:\\zorko')
destination = 'zorko'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if 'teorija' in filename:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(directory, filename), os.path.join(target, filename))
```